# Как поставить посреди видео текст

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, я вот хочу на сайте сделать так чтобы был тэг video с autoplay mute loop и сделать так чтобы был посредине этого видео текст и фото [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вот код этой шняги которую хочу поместить в центр видео

```
    <div class="container text-center" style="margin-top: 150px;">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col" style="margin-top: 80px;">
      <h1>Schalker Online</h1>
      <p>Какой-то текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img class="animate_animated animate__fadeInRight" src="src/img/favicon.ico">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Еще раз. Хочу сделать так чтобы был текст и фото которые показаны выше, и на фоне видео с автовоспроизведением

Comment: если что то формат странички php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте нечто подобное

```
<div class="some-container">
  <div class="layer">
        video...
    </div>
    
    <div class="layer layer--content">
        <div class="container text-center" style="margin-top: 150px;">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                <div class="col" style="margin-top: 80px;">
                    <h1>Schalker Online</h1>
                    <p>Какой-то текст</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <img class="animate_animated animate__fadeInRight" src="src/img/favicon.ico">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .some-container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .layer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    .layer--content {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
```